# mass modification of several data frames names in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a mass modification of several data frames names in R.
Names all finish with ".csv" and I would like to remove these 4 caracters.
I'm trying with the following piece of code:

```
for (i in (length(ls()))) { 

  ls()[i] <- gsub("*.csv", "", ls()[i]) 

}
```

But I get the following error message :

```
Error in ls()[i] <- gsub("*.csv", "", ls()[i]) : 
  invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

Any one has an idea?

Thank you very much !!

Mick

Comment: You can't rename an object like that. And why would you want to?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple approach;

```
# get object names
obj <- ls(pattern = "\\.csv$") 

# create new names and assign to global environment
list2env(setNames(mget(obj), sub("\\.csv$", "", obj)), globalenv())

# remove 'old' objects
rm(list = obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Renaming things is probably one valid use of `assign` and `get`, but you can't directly rename, you have to copy and remove the old object.

Sample objects:

```
> x.csv=1;y.csv=22;z.csv=333
```

We have:

```
> ls()
[1] "x.csv" "y.csv" "z.csv"
```

We loop, making sure we do everything in `.GlobalEnv`:

```
> sapply(ls(pattern="\\.csv$"),function(n){
        assign(gsub(".csv","",n),get(n),envir=.GlobalEnv);
        remove(list=n,envir=.GlobalEnv)
        })
```

And now we have:

```
> ls()
[1] "x" "y" "z"
> x
[1] 1
> y
[1] 22
> z
[1] 333
>
```

Comment: If you want to guard against pathological cases you should set the pattern in your `gsub` the same as the pattern in your `ls`. Though hopefully the OP isn't relying on this to rename their `.csv.csv` variable ;)